# Entity Framework Very Large Table to List

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table in my Microsoft SQL server with about 11,450,112 rows, I'am tring to use this command:

contex.TableName.ToList();

The problem is becuase the table is so big, the VB2010 throws an "OutOfMemory" exception.

I was thinking maybe theres a command to seprarete the query in to pages or something like that.

Any ideas or any help would help me very much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do paging with Entity Framework,

```
contex.TableName.Skip(pages*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

In the client side you need to implement some paging mechanism to pass the `page` and `pageSize` parameters according to the users input.

[Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) is a tutorial