# Big Tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I have an WEB SQL in Windows Azure Server, and I need search an item in a table with 40.000 rows. The execution time of the query is one minute, too long for a web app (or any kind of application..). What ai do for reduce this time?

My question is similar to this: [Entity Framework Very Large Table to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863578/entity-framework-very-large-table-to-list), but the answer is no acceptable because the method of paging is large too.

Code with search:

```
    public ActionResult SearchNcm(string typeSearch, string searchString)
    {
        var ncms = repository.VIEWNCM.ToList();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                switch (typeSearch)
                {
                    case "cod":
                        ncms = ncms.Where(e => e.CODIGO_LEITURA.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) || e.CODIGO.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;
                    default:
                        ncms = ncms.Where(e => e.DESCRICAO.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }



        return PartialView("BuscarNcm", ncms);
    }
```

Comment: what do you want 40k rows for? do you really need to load ALL of them in memory?

Comment: Sorry, I update the question. I really do not need to have the 40 000 rows in memory, but the search on this table is very time consuming.

Comment: Post the LINQ query and other relevant code.

Comment: Will repository.VIEWNCM.ToList() return all 40,000 rows into memory? It looks like you're loading the entire table and then doing your filtering/searching in memory.

Comment: Yes, that's right.
In the case, what better way to do the query?

Comment: Are there any circumstances where you NEED 40,000 rows? If not then you should do all your filtering (and probably sorting) BEFORE calling ToList(). This means you'll have to have some sort of default filter otherwise your View will execute the query rather than your Action method.

Comment: By the way - any sort of search involving Contains is going to be slow. You might want to look at Lucene.NET for text searching (as I believe Azure doesn't support Full Text indexes).

Comment: There is no circumstance where I need the 40,000 lines. But as I apply the filter before you have data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but I need the space to expand on my comment above:

Remember that IQueryable and IEnumerable won't do anything until you either iterate or call ToList(). That means you can do things like:

```
var ncms = repository.VIEWNCM; // this should be IQueryable or IEnumerable - no query yet

if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        switch(typeSearch)
        {
                case "cod":
                    // No query here either!
                    ncms = ncms.Where(e => e.CODIGO_LEITURA.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) || e.CODIGO.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
                    break;
                default:
                    // Nor here!
                    ncms = ncms.Where(e => e.DESCRICAO.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
// This is the important bit - what happens if the request is not an AJAX request?
else
{
    ncms = ncms.Take(1000); // eg, limit to first 1000 rows
}

return PartialView("BuscarNcm", ncms.ToList()); // finally here we execute the query before going to the View
```

You probably also need a default filter if the searchString is empty

Comment: This answer my question.